# I have only guest account. How do I create new account with administrative privileges?

Tags: command-line, users, administrator

I have only guest account in my Ubuntu. There  is no other account and I am unable to use `sudo`. So, how do I create a new account so that I can use `sudo`?

Comment: Connecting to Wifi is possible from Guest account afaik. How does the installation of Windows related to Guest account? They are completely independent things. `sudo` command is intended for Admin accounts only and guest account does not have administrative privileges. So what's your question? How to create Admin account?

Comment: Yes.  I would like to create administrator or atleast user account.  Now theres is only guest session  and i cannot use my laptop properly  because as soon as i turn of pc everything dissapears.  While i am in a guest session  i cant do anything. It's new laptop, never had any accounts on it.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo` command can be used by the accounts which have administrative privileges. Guest account does not have such privileges. Thus, you can't use `sudo` there. Also, there is no other account except guest, you need to create a new account with administrative privileges from recovery mode.

To create a new account with administrative privileges, follow the instructions step by step:

- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> as soon as system power on to see GRUB menu. GRUB menu looks like this:

  [image: ![GRUB]
- Go to **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and select any kernel version with *(recovery mode)*

  [image: Advanced Options for Ubuntu]
- Select `root` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for maintenance

  [image: root]
- You'll get a prompt as `root@hostname`. Run `useradd` for adding user and `passwd` to set password. Also, to run `sudo` commands you need to add this user in sudoer list.

  ```
  useradd <username>
  passwd <username>
  adduser <username> sudo
  reboot
  ```

  [image: Adding user]
- Account is now created. You can login with the password you have provided earlier.

  [image: Login Screen]
- `sudo` must work now. Open a terminal to check if it works.